# Running 6 monitors with 2 radeon hd5700

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have 2 Radeon 5700's each containing

1. 2 dvi ports
2. 1 hdmi port
3. 1 display port

I am aware that with one HD5700 i can run 3 monitors, but i would like to know..

`if i have 2 x HD5700 can they each run 3 monitors simultaneously?`

Comment: If they could [which they probably can, theoretically] I hope you wouldn't want them to do anything trickier than an Excel spreadsheet - they would collapse under the strain if asked to do 3D. Old cards & slow even for their day.

Comment: of course i understand, its for displaying generic graphics nothing  gaming wise! Thanks for the response though! @Tetsujin

Answer (score 0):

> If i have 2 x HD5700 can they each run 3 monitors simultaneously?

Yes. As long as you do not enable crossfire both cards can output to up to three monitors. (If you enable it one cards outputs will be turned off).